# Problemas para executar/publicar WEP API no IIS10!

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, iis

Eu quero publicar minha Web API ASP.NET via *filesystem*, mas estou tendo um erro de assembly ao rodar o site no IIS10.

Pelo VS eu consigo rodar, mas pelo IIS não.

OBS: já estou com a DLL na pasta bin.

Erro:

> Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly 'Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform...

Comment: Qual versão do .net está send compilado sua webApi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Quem utiliza Roslyn para publicação

Se seu projeto possui **referências Roslyn** e você está interessado em publicá-lo em um **servidor ISS**, você provavelmente irá ter erros indesejados no seu website visto que muitos provedores de *hosting* ainda não atualizaram seus servidores e consequentemente não suportam Roslyn.

Para resolver esse problema, **você terá que remover o compilador Roslyn do projeto**. Remover o Roslyn não deverá afetar a funcionalidade do seu código. Funcionou tranquilamente para mim e em outros projetos (C# 4.5.2) nos quais trabalhei.

Faça os seguintes passos:

1. Remova os seguintes pacotes Nuget usando a linha de comando informada abaixo (*ou você pode usar o gerenciador de Pacotes Nuget clicando com o botão direito a Raiz da Solução do seu Projeto e removendo-as*).

   ```
   PM> Uninstall-package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform
   PM> Uninstall-package Microsoft.Net.Compilers
   ```
2. Remova o seguinte código do arquivo Web.Config. *Utilize esse método apenas se o passo 1 não resolver seu problema.*

   ```
   <system.codedom>
   <compilers>
     <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
     <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
   </compilers>
   ```

**Reinicie seu IIS** e seu problema deve ser resolvido.

*Traduzido e adaptado de [IIS publishing problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319675/the-codedom-provider-type-microsoft-codedom-providers-dotnetcompilerplatform-cs/42668206#42668206)*.

Comment: Já esta adicionado, mas o problema é no IIS. Pois eu também já dei Update no pacote do NuGet :/

Comment: Você consegue rodar local pelo IIS? Ou o seu problema é só na hora de publicar ele?

Comment: Consigo rodar local pelo 'VS' mas o problema é na hora de publicar mesmo.

Comment: Você está utilizando Roslyn para publicar sua aplicação? Existe alguma pasta Roslyn no seu projeto?

Comment: Sim existe a pasta Roslyn.

Comment: Se eu fizer isso ele da erro também, o seguinte erro :

*The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Home/Index.aspx
~/Views/Home/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Home/Index.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml*

Comment: Isso é problema de Path da sua aplicação. Assim como o erro informa, ele não achou a view Index. Mas isso não deveria acontecer, visto que é uma Web API e a mesma não deve ter páginas (Views).

Comment: Sim eu não mexi em nada no projeto  criei um novo e esta dando o mesmo erro.

Comment: A única View que sua API deveria ter é a da Home, a qual depois irá chamar a API em si. Na hora de criar a API você marcou a opção Web Forms, por um acaso? Acabei de criar uma API aqui e ela funcionou perfeitamente (não marquei a opção Web Forms).